# Initial response NOT contains the value of a CustomField Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, djongo

These are the packages I'm using

```
django==3.0.5
djangorestframework==3.11.0
markdown==3.2.1
django-filter==2.3.0
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
djongo==1.3.3
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
```

I have a model like below

```
class IdField(models.Field):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "char(1000)"

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        print("pre_save"+ str(uuid.uuid4()))
        return uuid.uuid4()

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        print("print(value)",value)
        return value


class Parishioner(models.Model):

    def _age(self):
        return date.today().year - self.dob.year

    """Parishioner model"""
    id = IdField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dob = models.DateField()
    age = property(_age)
    GENDER_CHOICES = [("Male", "Male"), ("Female", "Female"), ("Other", "Other")]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    mothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    baptism_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=upload_image)
    marriage_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=upload_image)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

When I send my **POST** request my endpoint `api/parishioners/`
I get a successful **initial response** like below

```
{
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Perera",
    "dob": "1988-02-27",
    "age": 33,
    "gender": "Male",
    "address": "No 40, Katukurunda",
    "fathers_name": "JohnF",
    "mothers_name": "JohnM",
    "baptism_certificate": null,
    "marriage_certificate": null
}
```

as you can see my **"id"** field is **EMPTY**

But when I check database **id** filed is actually populated.
Then sent a **GET** request again to my end point `api/parishioners/`
I got below response

```
[
    {
        "id": "9aae45d2-86fc-4058-80f6-c38fa37ef597",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Perera",
        "dob": "1988-02-27",
        "age": 33,
        "gender": "Male",
        "address": "No 40, Katukurunda",
        "fathers_name": "JohnF",
        "mothers_name": "JohnM",
        "baptism_certificate": null,
        "marriage_certificate": null
    }
]
```

As you can see from the response **id** field is populated.
So Why **id** field is **EMPTY** in my initial response to my **POST** request ?
I just need to create my custom id field.

Comment: And what's your question?  This is exactly how it's supposed to work, right?  On initial creation, you don't know the ID until you create the database record and a new GUID is assigned.

Comment: @TimRoberts Then how come IF I comment this id = IdField(unique=True, primary_key=True)  instead of using my custom field type initial respose returns the id ?

Comment: We have no idea what's generating your "response", nor where in the process it happens.  Your 'id' value doesn't get assigned until "pre_save".  We don't when that is invoked.

Comment: @TimRoberts when should I generate my 'id' value ?
I mean at what method ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing now?